# How do I get the classic file structure display in 12.04 file manager?

Tags: gnome, display, directory

New 12.04 installation: How do I set up a classic file access display, with drives and folders? I may grow to like the default setup but until then I would like the familiarity of the older system.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "file structure display" hasn't changed in 12.04 compared to any previous version of Ubuntu. Could you please clarify your question, maybe with some screenshots?

Comment: I assume, he wants the previous default window (with Drives icon) when you open nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is the tree view, with the drives and folders displayed on the left:

[image]

You can get this by going to the View Menu for File Manager, and change the Sidebar to the Tree view option instead of Places:

[image]

The "detailed" view on the right is the List view; you can also change it to a compact view (no details), or a large view (icons) as John has explained in his answer.

Comment: Thank you; Yes the tree is what I wanted. Unfortunately I think I have a faulty install. My System Settings icon disappeared from the unity bar when I selected "high Contrast" theme, and when I drag something to the launch it puts it there but no icon, just a blank space. Mousepad scrolling is eratic, sometimes stopping. Plus I have got file system error messages. I think I will just re-install it since it was a new install and I have no data to worry about.

Comment: @msanderz, see my answer to your other question -- that is a known bug for High Contrast, so re-installing won't fix it. Considering you wanted the tree view, please remember to accept this answer (check/tick mark on left) so that the question can be marked as "answered." :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To bring up the Nautilus file access display press the top button in the Launcher bar and type *Files* into the HUD. Then Click on the Folder Icon with the little house displayed.

---

If you are getting a list of files and want icons for files and folder icons for folders instead, this can be adjusted with Nautilus' View Menu.

With the list display window selected, move the mouse to the top left and you will see Nautulus menus. Select View->Icons. A shortcut is to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>1</kbd> while the file access display window is active.